# With HaskellStack install packages to use with GHC without stack

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I install GHC on Windows10 using the recommended [Haskell Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/).  I want to us GHC without all the Stack overhead for [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com/).  This was working fine until I tried to get the [`extra`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.8) package.

I can install it with Stack, but I don't seem to have a way to get it in the global package database.  Haskell Stack apparently does not install the cabal executable and seems to have it locked out of their package database.

How do I install the `extra` package for use with vanilla GHC?

```
John Miller@DESKTOP-NENAGQH MSYS /d/dev/AdventOfCode2020
$ stack ghc -- AoC/Utils.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling AoC.Utils        ( AoC\Utils.hs, AoC\Utils.o )

John Miller@DESKTOP-NENAGQH MSYS /d/dev/AdventOfCode2020
$ ghc AoC/Utils.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling AoC.Utils        ( AoC\Utils.hs, AoC\Utils.o ) [Data.List.Extra changed]

AoC\Utils.hs:3:1: error:
    Could not find module `Data.List.Extra'
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
3 | import Data.List.Extra
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Using a single global environment for all of your projects is not the recommended approach of using `stack` or any other sane dev environment for that matter, but if that is what you want you can place all of your dependencies into `extra-deps` section of global `stack.yaml`, path to which you can get by running `stack path --config-location` outside of any other stack project.

Comment: This works with `stack ghc -- [...]` but does not help with `ghc [...]` I want to use ghc by itself for advent of code because setting up a stack for each day for a 15 minute coding challenge is not worth the effort.

Comment: I dare you try and build the `extra` dependency you want using only `ghc` and `ghc-pkg` without relying on either `stack`,  `cabal` or `nix`. You need a build tool that knows where package is located, so it can tell your ghc compiler about that location and do all the necessary linking. With `stack`, a single ghc version is installed only once, so you will not get a new ghc installed for each challenge. Take a word of advice, just use `stack ghc` or `stack exec -- ghc`. Or even better create a single package with a separate executable section in cabal file for each day of challenge.

Comment: Yes! That is correct! How do I get stack to do what I want? The old haskell platform never gave me this much grief.  Where is cabal?  Why won't stake just make all the packages available if I'm not in a project? Is there a way to get back to just GHC and Cabal for smal things like advent of code?

Comment: Because you want the wrong thing. History showed that this approach is incorrect. If you don't realize it yet that means you have never experienced cabal hell. Even cabal started using cabal.project files for that reason. 
FYI, you can use `stack --system-ghc` if you do not want stack to manage ghc installations.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know whether `stack` supports installing to the global package DB. `cabal` does though:

```sh
$ cabal install --lib extra
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.10.2: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded package environment from /home/simon/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.10.2/environments/default
Prelude> import Data.List.Extra 
Prelude Data.List.Extra>
```

Comment: please reread the question: 
$ cabal install --lib extra
-bash: cabal: command not found

Comment: Yeah. You'll need to install `cabal` to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so `stack` can install the cabal executable if you beat at it long enough.  The package is called `cabal-install` and it is not in any resolver, but is on Hackage.

```
stack install cabal-install
```

Because it is not in the resolver there is a pretty good chance that the version of `Cabal`, the library for manipulating cabal packages in Haskell, is not compatible. First, ask `stack` where it keeps its global config

```
stack path --config-location
```

Edit that file to allow for the needed dependencies under `extra-deps:` Stack will helpfully tell you what they are. It may also be helpful to change the resolver to a newer version in that file while your at it.

Now try

```
stack install cabal-install
```

again and if these instructions have not fallen out of date since December 2020 you will get the cabal executable somewhere potentially useful.

Before using `cabal` you will have to run a `cabal update` to get the package list.

At this point cabal should manipulate your global package database and `stack` can install GCH and all its libraries over and over and over again if you want to use it for a project instead.  They should just keep out of each other's way.